# How can I redirect a user to homepage if they change the url manually?

Tags: php, redirect

Let's say the user is in the page --> mysite.com/product.php?id=5
and he manually removed the ?id=5 and r=the url became this way--> mysite.com/product.php

How can I redirect him to the homepage?

Comment: what would be the purpose of this?

Comment: 404 would be better in this case. Silent redirects are bad solution to almost any problem.

Comment: I'd highly recommend explaining why you're doing this if you want a 100% correct answer. What if someone types that into the browser *without* removing the `?id=5`? or what if they change it to `?id=4`... there's much to consider in my opinion

Answer (score 2):

Just check to see if the id is missing from the query string. If so, do the redirect.

```
if (!isset($_GET['id']) || empty($_GET['id'])) {
    //redirect
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you still want the page to be accessible if Parameters are set use this method:

```
if(!isset($_GET)){
    header("Location: http://mysite.com/");
    exit;
}
```

Check to see if no variables have been passed to the page, and then redirect accordingly.
`exit` after the Header to be sure that no text is sent to the browser that will break the header.

If this will become a dead page, use a 403:

```
header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
header ("Location: http://mysite.com/");
```

Comment: Not a problem. If this helped be sure to UpVote and Accept :)